# Vim substitution not happening correctly in command line mode when using single quotes

Tags: bash, shell, vim

i have a file test.txt with data init=6'b000000; and i want to replace it with init=6'b110111; by using vim script in a bash file. I'm getting error

I'm using following command:

```
vim -c '%s/init=6'b000000;/init=6'b110111;/g | write | quit' test.txt
```

this works perfectly in vim, not in bash .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Vim`, you cannot embed a single quote inside a pair of other single quotes. The shell parses the command line arguments before passing them to the invoked command and it just cannot deal with the inner single quote in the way you have defined.

The literal single quote inside need to be preserved before passing to the command. So use double quote and escape the inner quote

```
vim -c "%s/init=6\'b000000;/init=6\'b110111;/g | write | quit" file
```

or use the single quote, but include a multi-level double quote inside

```
vim -c '%s/init=6'"\'"'b000000;/init=6'"\'"'b110111;/g | write | quit' file
```